# Need assistance in repair of corrupted Inndob table

Tags: mysql, innodb, corrupt, repair

Our Magento website has been having problems lately and every now and then we receive on our webpage an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1712 Index [table] is corrupted
```

As i understand, innodb does not support repair via phpmyadmin. We are able to shutoff website and database for a few hours in order to repair but do not understand repair well enough after reading online.

Would appreciate any help on repair of innodb tables.

Answer (score -2):

What version of MySQL?

1712 is very rare.  See if [Bug 72858](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72868) is relevant.

Here is a way to rebuild (not "repair") the index(es):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If that does not help, please provide any output from the `ALTER`, including execution time.

Comment: MySQL version: 5.6.29

Comment: Doesn't the linked bugreport just indicate that MySQL server query optimizer should avoid using the index in case of corruption? How can this be relevant?

Comment: I was not sure whether it was relevant; that is the only one I could find.